# LIMT query to 1 if selcted two tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to limit query to 100 if i have selected data from two tables.

But i want the limit 100 to only work on one of them.

```
SELECT c.* , p.* 
FROM test c,test2 p 
WHERE c.id=p.id_puf  
LIMIT 100
```

But here is the tricky part(at least for me)

In table "test" ja hold names.

Structure:

```
ID, Name, Age
```

Table "test2" ja hold record of the persons and they are connected with user ID

Structure:

```
ID, connect(this is same as "test" id), numbers
```

Now every tabel row in "test" is unique

I want to get all the results for test but all the record from the "test2".

Comment: Inner join I think which will give you all records from table one and matching from table 2

Comment: @YashveerSingh -- the code he posted is an inner join

Comment: @Hogan ohh so sorry my mistake .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would do it -- select the items from the first table you want and then join to the 2nd table.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM test
  LIMIT 100
) c
LEFT JOIN test2 p ON c.id=p.id_puf
```

Notice I'm using "modern" joins.  The join style you were using is about 20 years out of date and is not as good.  It is much clearer how to solve this problem if you are using modern joins (for example).

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm :)
If i want to add WHERE to second table "p" in this case, then i just write it on the end of the query?
LEFT JOIN test2 p ON c.id=p.id_puf WHERE p.connect!="" and so?